# Deleting from a multi dimensional array

Tags: php

I need to delete from a multi dimensional array.

My array looks as follows

```
Array(
   0 => Array(
      0 => "My Album",
      1 => "Testphoto2011-222231.jpg"
   ),
   1 => Array(
      0 => "Test Album",
      1 => "12345.jpg"
   )
);
```

What I want to do is search the value `"My Album"` and then delete the entire array from the array.

So for example the values `"My Album"` & `"Testphoto2011-222231.jpg"` belong to `array[0]`. When found I want to delete `array[0]`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ar = Array(
   Array(
      "My Album",
      "Testphoto2011-222231.jpg"
   ),
   Array(
      "Test Album",
      "12345.jpg"
   )
);

// Not using foreach, or ascending counting, because
// element removal will screw that up.
for ($i = count($ar) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
   if ($ar[$i][0] == "My Album")
      unset($ar[$i]);
}

$ar = array_values($ar); // re-index

var_export($ar);

/* Output:
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Test Album',
    1 => '12345.jpg',
  ),
)
*/
?>
```

[Live demo.](http://codepad.org/pze95gXm)

Comment: Brilliant thanks, i just have one question, My array is in a session, I used this code

for ($i = count($_SESSION['albums']) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
   if ($_SESSION['albums'][$i][0] == $album)
      unset($_SESSION['albums'][$i]);
}

$_SESSION['albums'] = array_values($_SESSION['albums']); // re-index

var_export($_SESSION['albums']);

is this right? At the moment its not updating the session array

Comment: @Wayne: Please use backticks to format code. And yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 0):

`unset($array[0])` will remove that entry from the array.